# Jackson - Conversão de objetos com dependência circular

Tags: java, json, jackson

Dadas as classes abaixo, precisamos resolver o problema de recursão infinita (dependência cíclica) e, para isso, utilizamos a @JsonIdentityInfo, do Jackson 2+:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=Parent.class, generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Parent {

    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private List<Child> filhos;

}

@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=Child.class, generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Child {

    private Long id;

    private Parent pai;

    private String nome;
}
```

Estamos com problemas ao converter as entidades acima para JSON. Na verdade, a conversão de objetos do tipo Parent ocorre como esperado ...

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "nome":"PAI1",
   "filhos":[  
      {  
         "id":10,
         "pai":1,
         "nome":"FILHO1"
      },
      {  
         "id":11,
         "pai":1,
         "nome":"FILHO2"
      }
   ]
}
```

... porém, o mesmo não ocorre ao tentar converter objetos do tipo Child individualmente ou em listas ...

individual:

```
{
   "id":10,
   "pai":{
      "id":1,
      "nome":"PAI1",
      "filhos":[
         10,
         {
            "id":11,
            "pai":1,
            "nome":"FILHO2"
         }
      ]
   },
   "nome":"FILHO1"
}
```

lista:

```
[
   {
      "id":10,
      "pai":{
         "id":1,
         "nome":"PAI1",
         "filhos":[
            10,
            {
               "id":11,
               "pai":1,
               "nome":"FILHO2"
            }
         ]
      },
      "nome":"FILHO1"
   },
   11
]
```

... esperávamos que o individual tivesse o atributo filhos como null e que a lista também os tivesse como null, além de retornar somente objetos, e não objeto/id, como ocorreu...

resultado individual esperado:

```
{
   "id":10,
   "pai":{
      "id":1,
      "nome":"PAI1",
      "filhos":null (ou [])
   },
   "nome":"FILHO1"
}
```

resultado em lista esperado:
lista:

```
[
   {
      "id":10,
      "pai":{
         "id":1,
         "nome":"PAI1",
         "filhos":null (ou [])
      },
      "nome":"FILHO1"
   },
   {
      "id":11,
      "pai":{
         "id":1,
         "nome":"PAI1",
         "filhos":null (ou [])
      },
      "nome":"FILHO2"
   }   
]
```

Segue abaixo o método main executado que retorna o resultado acima:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Parent pai = new Parent();
    pai.setId(1L);
    pai.setNome("PAI1");

    List<Child> filhos = new ArrayList<Child>();
    filhos.add(new Child(10L, pai, "FILHO1"));
    filhos.add(new Child(11L, pai, "FILHO2"));

    pai.setFilhos(filhos);

    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(pai));
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(filhos));
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(filhos.get(0)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvemos usando outra abordagem: ao invés de usar a @JsonIdentityInfo, estou usando @JsonView, com a versão do Spring 4.1+ e Jackson 2.5+. Para mais detalhes, veja o seguinte tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring